# Cannot configure ESC: BLHeli-Configuator connects but with blank screen

Tags: blheli

ESC: GEPRC STABLE PRO F7 ESC BL32 2-6S 4in1 Specs：35A BLheli_32 ESC

Steps to connect to BLHeli-Configurator:

1. Connect to flight control (GEPRC STABLE PRO F7 35A) via mini usb
2. Connect Lipo Battery to drone
3. Open BLHeli-Configurator from my Windows 10 laptop
4. Click Connect on the top right corner of BLheli-Configurator. Note, COMM is being read by the configurator
5. Click Read Setup on the bottom right corner.
6. On logs, it states:
   "2020-06-14 @ 13:30:59 -- Reading setup.
   2020-06-14 @ 13:31:00 -- Reading setup finished."
7. Screen is still blank and can't access the ESC items.

Beta flight is not opened while going through this process.
Experienced this on two drones with the same ESC(built two drones in my life).

Trying to change the spin on my motors, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [BLHeliSuite32](https://oscarliang.com/blheli-32-esc-fc-passthrough/) instead, since it is a BLHeli_32. I don't think BLHeli configurator works with 32 bit ESC:s, correct me if I'm wrong.

If that does not work, try having Betaflight configurator open WITHOUT connecting. This has helped me sometimes.

If it still does not work, you might need to connect to the ESC without using passthrough (if possible) and try to reflash it with a newer BLHeli_32 version.

Comment: "*I don't think BLHeli configurator works with 32 bit ESC:s*" — That's correct. :)

Comment: That's probably the problem then :)

Comment: Really appreciate the clarification. Yes, that worked and was able to reverse the specified motors. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!